Error duplicate name ‘ActivityHeartbeat’ in Namespace coresdk
The company uses a lib called Temporalio and after adding com aws libs I’m getting an error saying that I have a duplicate name when I’m starting the server or trying to run unit tests. I was suspecting of version and libs conflicts, but I've tried to leave all libs with the same version, but it haven't worked.
The error messages is
node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:239
                throw Error("duplicate name '" + object.name + "' in " + this);
                      ^
Error: duplicate name 'ActivityHeartbeat' in Namespace coresdk
    at Namespace.add (node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:239:23)
    at Root.add (node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:232:28)
    at Root.addJSON (node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:172:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@temporalio/proto/protos/json-module.js:7:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at Module.Hook.Module.require (api/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/ritm.js:85:33)

when I run a test I get the same error for a specific test that uses the temporalio lib
duplicate name 'ActivityHeartbeat' in Namespace coresdk

      3 | const sdk = getTracerSdk();
      4 |
    > 5 | import {
        | ^
      6 |     Client,
      7 |     Connection,
      8 |     DataConverter,

      at Namespace.add (../node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:239:23)
      at Root.add (../node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:232:28)
      at Root.addJSON (../node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:172:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/proto/protos/json-module.js:7:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/proto/protos/root.js:8:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/proto/protos/index.js:1:120)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/client/src/types.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/client/src/connection.ts:11:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/client/src/base-client.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/client/src/async-completion-client.ts:10:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@temporalio/client/src/index.ts:30:1)

I'm even don't what is causing this error or how to solve it
